# How to validate the username textfield in a form in php

Tags: php, forms

I want to check in the username text field to be typed only letters how can i do it in PHP? Plus in the password area to input both letters and numbers. When I click the `Register` button it displays Successful Registration although the form is not filled and I also put an `else` statement to display a message to fill all the fields.

the form

```
<form action = "register.php" method = "POST">


    Username: <input type="text" name="username" > <br /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br /><br/>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="repassword"> <br /><br/>

    Type:
    <select name="type">
    <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT type FROM type");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo "<option value='".$row['type']."'>".$row['type']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
</form>
```

the register code

```
<?php

require('connect.php');

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$repass=$_POST['repassword'];
$type=$_POST['type'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //input only letters in username textfield

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['type'])){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, type) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$type')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "Successful Registration";
    }

    if(!$result){

        $msg = "User Failed to be Registered.";  
    }
}

else{
     echo "Please fill all the fields.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't validate the userinput with the isset() function. Instead use **!empty()**.
Because isset() also returns true if the POST variable is an empty string.

Also be careful with your SQL-Query ([SQL-Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)), you have to escape the $_POST inputs.
You can use this code

```
$username = real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
$password = real_escape_string ($_POST['password']);
$type = real_escape_string($_POST['type']); //if type is int, use intval() to escape
```

BTW: you don't validate the password against the repassword.

Comment: like this '!empty($_POST['username'])' ?

Comment: I get this error: 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_escape_string() ' for the $username.

Comment: Sorry the method is mysqli_real_escape_string()